# Returning instance created in 'using' statement

Tags: c#, using

If I have this method:

```
public StreamReader GetResourceStream(string filename)
{
    using (Stream stream = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(filename))
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        return sr;
    }
}
```

When I call it, should I call it this way

```
StreamReader resource = GetResourceStream("blah.xml");
```

or this way:

```
using (StreamReader resource = GetResourceStream("blah.xml"))
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

If second way, does this means the `using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))` line is not making any difference by using a `using` statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't really make sense to have the `GetResourceStream` method put the using statement around the object it's returning.  That means you will be returning an object in a disposed state, and what good is that? It will throw `ObjectDisposed` exceptions at you.

So remove the `using` statements inside your factory method, and apply the `using` statement where you're actually *using* it.

It should look more like this:

```
public StreamReader GetResourceStream(string filename)
{
    Stream stream = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(filename);
    return new StreamReader(stream)        
}
```

Comment: You mean both `using` inside `GetResourceStream` or just the second one?

Comment: I can see by Jon's code that I don't need to use a `Stream` but I can create a `StreamReader` directly, but I'm curious now, If I'd use your code above, who would dispose the `Stream stream` object (not the `StreamReader`; now I understand I'd dispose that one from the caller code?

Comment: @Ahmet Both code samples do create a `Stream`.  The `StreamReader` presumably calls dispose on the underlying stream when it is disposed too, although I haven't found documentation showing that yet.

Comment: @Ahmet A quick experiment in linqpad shows that this is the case. The `StreamReader` disposes of the underlying `Stream`.

Comment: There are a few cases where it may make sense to return an object from within a `Using`.  The code which draws many WinForms controls, for example, will take the pass-in `Font` property, create a new font with the same attributes, draw with that, and then dispose the new font.  Consequently, controls don't care if their `Font` property is set to a disposed font.  Disposing of fonts immediately upon creation, before assigning them to controls, may seem odd, but it's much easier than trying to figure out when a particular font is no longer needed.

Comment: It is not clear for me who and where it is ensured that the manifest stream will be disposed (I am talking not the StreamReader, instead the Stream which is created inside GetManifestResourceStream() call

Answer (score 7):

You should change the method itself *not* to include a `using` statement, but then make sure that the *calling* code uses a `using` statement:

```
public StreamReader GetResourceStream(string filename)
{
    return new StreamReader(GetType().Assembly
                                     .GetManifestResourceStream(filename));
}

using (StreamReader resource = GetResourceStream("blah.xml"))
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

That way it will only dispose of the resource when you've actually *used* it. Basically the method is giving ownership of the returned resource to the caller. That much isn't too bad - it's reasonably common, even (think of `File.OpenText` etc).

Where it gets more tricky is when you *pass a resource into a method or constructor* - should the "called" code take ownership or not? Usually not, but occasionally it's appropriate - for example, the [`Bitmap(Stream)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7ha67kw.aspx) documentation states that you must keep the stream alive for as long as the bitmap is required. In fact, disposing of the bitmap *also* disposes of the stream, so you still only have one resource to keep track of... but you do need to know that you mustn't close the stream.

Comment: Per your code, I understand you don't need to create a `Stream` in the middle as I did but just create a `StreamReader` directly, but I'm curious, how would you do if you'd need to create a `Stream` and pass it to the constructor of `StreamReader`? (There are case AFAIK where you need to create an intermediary stream).

Comment: @Ahmet: I'd just create a stream as normal - and trust that there'd be no exceptions between creating it and passing it to the StreamReader. If you were paranoid you could always create a finally block and dispose the stream *only if* we hadn't reached the StreamReader constructor, or something like that.

Comment: @Ahmet: Note that my code creates the same number of streams as yours - it just doesn't use a separate local variable for the stream it creates.

Comment: It is not clear for me who and where it is ensured that the manifest stream will be disposed (I am talking not the StreamReader, instead the Stream which is created inside GetManifestResourceStream() call

Comment: @g.pickardou: When you dispose of the `StreamReader`, that disposes of the `Stream` it contains.

Comment: @JonSkeet: many thanks for the instant answer. My concern was, that it must be the part of the specification, and the implementation is a weak point to ensure. In more general, this is always a question, when two (or more) disposable resource usage is nested, but not syntactically via two nested using constructs instead via the control flow...

Comment: @g.pickardou: It depends on how the nesting works - the classes responsible. For example, [the documentation for the `StreamReader(Stream)` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_StreamReader__ctor_System_IO_Stream_) explicitly states: "The StreamReader object calls Dispose() on the provided Stream object when StreamReader.Dispose is called." So I think it's fine to rely on that. If you're dealing with something that doesn't provide as much documentation, it's trickier.

Answer (score 2):

When program flow exits the second using block, sr.Dispose() will be called, disposing the StreamReader and making it useless.

You need to make use of sr before flow control exits that block.

Comment: So my `GetResourceStream` method should not use the 2nd `using` if I understand correctly?

Comment: @Ahmet: You need to dispose of the resource somewhere, but if you're going to return sr, you need to dispose of it where you use it and not wrap it in a using block there.

Comment: @Ahmet: Added an example of what I mean to the response.

Comment: All variations shown are broken.  You're returning a dangling `StreamReader`, the underlying `Stream` has already been closed.

Comment: @Ben: Yeah just noticed.  Back to my original suggestion... use sr in the original using block.